# UPSERT: use source column that's not in excluded table

Tags: oracle, postgresql, merge, upsert

I'm trying to convert an oracle `Merge` statement to postgreSQL(>9.5).
Unfortunately postgres(=<11) still doesn't support `MERGE` and the best alternative method I found was the `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` also called `UPSERT`.

I was able to convert the more basic merge statement into upserts but for more complex queries I need to access columns from the source query the are not inserted but only used for logic in the `DO UPDATE`. 
Unfortunately the special `excluded.`-table uses the same column identifiers as the target.

**ORACLE MERGE version**

```sql
MERGE INTO tgt
  USING (SELECT nam.text AS normalizedtext, norm.originaltext,
           norm.entryid AS entryID,
           nam.name_id AS name_id,
           norm.islink AS islink
         FROM norm, nam
         WHERE norm.name_id = nam.name_id
         GROUP BY originaltext
        ) source
  ON (tgt.languagecode = :langCode AND tgt.text = source.originaltext)
  WHEN MATCHED AND ptid IS NULL THEN
    UPDATE SET tgt.name_id = source.name_id,
               tgt.PTID = source.entryID,
               tgt.normname = CASE WHEN source.islink = 1 THEN 
               source.originaltext ELSE source.normalizedtext END CASE
```

**Current postgress version**

```sql
INSERT INTO tgt (text, normname, ptid, name_id, languagecode)
    SELECT nam.text AS normalizedtext, norm.originaltext,
           norm.entryid AS entryID,
           nam.name_id AS name_id,
           :langCode,           -- edited
           norm.islink AS islink
         FROM norm, nam
         WHERE norm.name_id = nam.name_id
         GROUP BY originaltext
ON CONFLICT (text, languagecode)
DO UPDATE
    SET name_id = excluded.name_id,
           ptid = excluded.ptid,
           normname = CASE WHEN excluded.islink = 1 THEN          -- PROBLEM
           excluded.originaltext ELSE excluded.normalizedtext END -- PROBLEM
    WHERE ptid IS NULL;
```

The problem is that the excluded table does not contain the columns: `isLink` , `originaltext` and `normalizedtext`.

> ERROR: column excluded.islink does not exist

Is there any workaround or how can u use the source columns in the update query?
If this is not possible, is there an other alternative to write merge statements in postgres?

Comment: The value from `norm.islink` is put into the column `languagecode` during the insert - that looks wrong to begin with. But if that is indeed correct you need to use the target's table column: `CASE WHEN excluded.languagecode = 1 THEN ...`

Comment: yes, thank you i just noticed that i forgot the `languagecode` in the SELECT. But i don't want that value to be inserted if there is no match. Could i use a dummy column name maybe thats not connected to the tgt table

Comment: Now your select statement contains more columns that you have INSERT target columns - this won't work even without the ON CONFLICT.

Answer (score 1):

You can move that CASE expression to the SELECT statement:

```
INSERT INTO tgt (text, normname, ptid, name_id, languagecode)
SELECT nam.text, 
       case islink 
         when 1 then norm.originaltext
         else normalizedtext
       end as normname,
       norm.entryid AS ptid,
       nam.name_id AS name_id,
       :langCode as languagecode
FROM norm
  JOIN nam ON norm.name_id = nam.name_id
GROUP BY originaltext
ON CONFLICT (text, languagecode)
DO UPDATE
    SET name_id = excluded.name_id,
           ptid = excluded.ptid,
           normname = excluded.normname
    WHERE ptid IS NULL;
```